# Can you do more than iterate through an array in Laravel Blades?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I have passed an array ($players) to my view, and I can easily iterate over it using @foreach within the blade, but what I am actually trying to do is check the entire array for a certain players name, then output all of his data in the blade. I plan on doing this using a dialog box. This would be all well and good if I was using a search feature, or something like that, but I am trying to just use jQuery-UI's Dialog() and some Javascript. Whenever a players name is hovered over, I'd like to run that query and display his stats.

Is it possible to search through an array in such a way in blade templating? I figure I can just compact all of the players into their own array and then pass it to the view, but this seems like too much work (in the sense that I feel this can be more automated). As of now, it's only 17 players, but I'd like this to work if it was 100 players.

Thanks

Comment: You can do t with javascript. Store the array in **JSON** object and so search operation according to player.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I will look into JSON!

Answer (score 0):

Blade templates are rendered server-side and it sounds like you want to search through the data based on a user doing something, i.e. on the client-side.

A crude way of doing this would be to write all your player data to into a javascript variable:

```
<script>
var playerData = {!! $player_data !!};
</script>
```

Where `$player_data` is passed to the view your PHP script.

Then you can search through `data` with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

In your view you could use laravel's helper function to filter your array by a specific player's name..yet im not sure if this is best way to get your result

//in this case its returning only the values that are strings
(example on laravels documentation)

```
$array = array_where($array, function ($key, $value) {
    return is_string($value);
});
```